# iOS App Store app icon: 1024x1024 or 3072x3072?

Tags: ios, icons, app-store

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Does the app icon for the iOS App Store need to be 3072 x 3072 px for the latest iPhone since it's an @3x scale factor device?

Comment: There's only one App Store icon in iTunes Connect. It's not specific to any device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the image sizes listed in the table are **absolute values**.

The Icon has to be of size `1024 x 1024`

In addition the app store icon is somewhat special since it is completely unaffected by the actual hardware. The device does not change the image size you need to provide for the store.

Comment: The image sizes listed in the table are absolute. For the springboard you have to provide a file for iphones @3 with size 180x180, one with @2 with size 120x120 etc. You do not have to do any math here. The values **are** the sizes you have to provide.

Comment: @The_Machine The 1024x1024 App Store icon has nothing at all to do with icon shown on the user's device for your app.